# Can i use folder name in views jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If i have folders in web-inf/jsp/person

can i return this in controller

```
return "person/userpage"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ViewResolver` configured properly if you wish to return such values.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"

class=" org.springframework.web.servlet.view. InternalResourceViewResolver" >

<property name="suffix">

<value>yourFile.jsp</value>

</property>

</bean
```

this view resolver will search for the `yourFile.jsp` in the returned `folder`

Comment: i can't put i view resolver because i have different folders for different controllers so i wanted to return folder from inside controller.